# managed metadata navigation and anonymous access

Tags: navigation, managed-metadata, anonymous-authentication

I have a library with metadata navigation. When anonymous users go to a navigation link, the web browser gives the 403 forbidden error. The error disappears when I turn off metadata navigation.

To display I'm using library default list form with Xslt List View Web Part.

I found [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff625176.aspx) about the same topic. I granted permissions to application pool and it has no effect.

Logs tell me very informative strings:
Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem with permissions of TaxonomyHiddenList

Comment: Did you make the change of permissions as per the article or something else?

Comment: I also manipulated TaxonomyHiddenList. As I remember, I had broke permissionce inheritence and repeir it.

Comment: Ok, I resolved my issue only with the permissions change to the Taxonomy Hidden List.